# Adding an NSTextAttachment with an image to NSMutableAttributedString does not appear immediately

Tags: macos, swift3

I'm trying to add an image to an NSMutableAttributedString via NSTextAttachment, the trouble is that the image doesn't seem to appear until I restart the app. Any ideas?

```
var attributesForThisSection = [String : Any]()

if key == NSAttachmentAttributeName {

    let base64Rep = (value as! String)

    if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Rep) {

        let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
        if let img = NSImage(data: data) {
            textAttachment.image = img
            attributesForThisSection[NSAttachmentAttributeName] = textAttachment
        }
        else {
            print("img from data not ok")
        }

    }

}
```

Then

```
let r = NSMakeRange(loc, len)
attributedString?.addAttributes(attributesForThisSection, range: r)
```

The text is displayed in an NSTextView, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was replace

```
textAttachment.image = img
```

With

```
let attachmentCell = NSTextAttachmentCell(imageCell: img)
textAttachment.attachmentCell = attachmentCell
```